# Calling main method

Tags: java

I have created a method that is called readfile. my method should read the Data and run readfile method in the main method. however when i tried to call my method in the main method it shows me cannot make static reference to the non static method readfile (string) from the type DataAnalysis. can someone help me how i can call the method in the main method with out making readfile static method?

Comment: `readFile` should be `static` as it doesn't use any instance fields or methods,

Answer (score 8):

You would have to create an instance of the DataAnalysis object.

```
DataAnalysis da = new DataAnalysis();
da.readfile("StateCrime.csv");
```

Answer (score 2):

`readfile` doesn't use any instance variables - you should just define it as `static`:

```
public static void readfile(String name) {
    // Your code here...
```

Comment: A solution.  But probably not the right one ... in general.

Comment: @StephenC I am of the view that any method which can be `static` should be, as making an instance method when it doesn't need to be is confusing.

Comment: Yes ... but my reading of this code is that it is going to turn into something that needs to be an instance method.

Answer (score 1):

**option1** make the method static

```
public static void readfile(String name){
```

**option2** make an object of the class and call it

```
DataAnalysis myDataAnal = new DataAnalysis();
myDataAnal.readfile(FILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

either make this function static

try this

`public static void readfile(String name)` instead Of `public void readfile(String name)`

and call as like this

`DataAnalysis.readfile(String name)`

OR

> make a object then call the method as like follows

```
DataAnalysis obj = new DataAnalysis();
obj.readfile("StateCrime.csv");
```